# Insert Text Node before Text Node without merging in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom

I would like to insert a text node before another text node like so:

```
<p id="4">text<b>!</b></p>
```

```
document.getElementById("4").childNodes[0].before("more ");
```

```
<p id="4">more text<b>!</b></p>
```

This works great, except in Chrome it will merge the text nodes:

```
<p>[#text more text]<b>!</b></p>
```

In Firefox, the text nodes do not merge:

```
<p>[#text more ][#text text]<b>!</b></p>
```

How do I get Chrome to act like Firefox? I have determined that it is not related to the `before()` method, because I have tried other methods of inserting the text. I am not interested in jQuery solutions.

Answer (score 0):

this solution is Compatible with all browsers

```js
let element = document.getElementById("4");
element.innerText =  "more " + element.innerText;
```

```html
<p id="4">text</p>
```

Comment: I would actually like there to be a new text node created.